# Markup Extension for converting ARGB to usable Hex for XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a MarkupExtension that returns Hex from an ARGB value that you can use in XAML.

```
public class FromArgbExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public FromArgbExtension() { }
    public FromArgbExtension(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b; 
    }

    public byte A { get; set; }
    public byte R { get; set; }
    public byte G { get; set; }
    public byte B { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    { 
        return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
    }
}

<DataGrid Background="{vl:FromArgbExtension 255, 217, 217, 217}"
```

The problem I am having is that it is throwing an error:  'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Panel.Background' threw an exception.' but the inner exception is:  {"'#FFD9D9D9' is not a valid value for property 'Background'."}

What I don't understand is that if I take #FFD9D9D9 and use it then it works just fine.

Comment: seems like a ValueConverter is a good solution.

Comment: Background is not Color, is a Brush, maybe that's it

Comment: Doh, you are right!  I had wondered why it was working previously for a different property but that's because that property did use color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to stop and think a little bit here... you want to use your Markup Extension on the `Background` property (of type `Brush`) like this:

```
<DataGrid Background="{vl:FromArgbExtension 255, 217, 217, 217}" ... />
```

However, your `ProvideValue` method returns a `Color`.

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{ 
    return Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B);
}
```

Therefore, your Markup Extension should return a `Brush` if you want to use it on a `Brush` property:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{ 
    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Background` Property expects a `Brush`, where you are returning a `Color`. Create a `SolidColorBrush` from the `Color` and return that:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B));
    solidColorBrush.Freeze();
    return solidColorBrush;
}
```

Comment: Nice addition of the Freeze.  I need to remember to Freeze things of this nature before returning them.  Thanks!

Comment: Freezing an object blindly like this is *not* a good idea... you don't know whether the user might want to data bind or animate the `Brush.Color` property. Furthermore, if you *are* going to `Freeze` an object then you should check the result of `CanFreeze` first... from the [`Freezable.Freeze` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN: *To avoid the possibility of an `InvalidOperationException` when calling this method, check the `CanFreeze` property to determine whether the `Freezable` can be made unmodifiable before calling this method.*

Comment: In this case, when would you expect the `CanFreeze` to return false?

Comment: @Sheridan And in what kind of situationn would freezing the brush harm data binding? `Brush` doesn't have the `Color` property, `SolidColorBrush` has. Animating a property using `ColorAnimation` (in XAML), like `Background`, where this `MarkupExtension` is used, works.